# Devise::TestHelpers docs unclear on Devise.mappings[:mapping] usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, devise

In the docs for using the Devise TestHelpers it states to use lines such as...

```
@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
```

or

```
@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

...to let Devise know which resource or mapping to use since the controller tests bypass routes.rb. I am not clear on what these mappings are. I have not set up anything special in this regard, and I do not have a specific mapping in mind. I have User, Admin, Refinery, and Superuser roles, a la Rolify, and I am using Cancan for its abilities.

Can you clarify? ...perhaps the resource name is what us meant?

TIA.
-Matt

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since waiting for an answer, my research seems to indicate that the mapping indicated in the documentation is actually referring to the resource against which Devise is attached.

*Following is speculative on my part, but it appears to work, and it agrees with my scan of the code.*
For example, if you have only one resource called User you have used Devise for authenticating, you would only need to use the following in your controller spec setup:

```
@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

However, if you have multiple models you are authenticating against, say User and Admin, you would need to use the following, respectively.

```
@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

and

```
@request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
```

Please feel free to update this question/answer if you have better input.